# SharePoint 2013 - Moving Child Subsite to another site collection

Tags: 2013, development, sub-site

I have a structure as follow:

**My Site (Root site)**

1. **Client 1**

   > **Division 1**

   ```
        >  Site 101
        >  Site 102
   ```

   > Division 2
2. **Client 2**

   > **Division 1**
   >
   > **Division 2**

In the above structure, how do I move "**Site 101**" from:

Client 1  >> Division 1

**TO**

Client 2  >> Division 2

How can this be achieved programmatically? (i.e. c-sharp)

---

Possible duplicate of SharePoint Online - Move Site and subsites into another site – Atish Dipongkor 16 mins ago

---->

It isn't duplicate as my question is to move the child subsites "**PROGRAMMATICALLY**"

"using powershell? or using c# etc? – Waqas Sarwar MCSE"

-- I am leaning more towards c#...possibly by using API's CSOM etc.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem

Comment: using powershell? or using c# etc?

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell.  Found on google.

## add SharePoint snapin

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell –ea SilentlyContinue

## set variables - FYI exportfolder will throw an error if folder is already created.

$exportfolder = "E:\SiteExports\NAME" 
$exportfile = "\NAME.cmp" 
$exportsite = "http://client1/divison1/site 101" 
$exportlocation = $exportfolder+$exportfile 
$importlocation = "http://client2/division2/site 101"

## get export site's template

$web = Get-SPWeb $exportsite 
$webTemp =  $web.WebTemplate 
$webTempID = $web.Configuration 
$webTemplate = "$webTemp#$webTempID" 
$web.Dispose()

## create export folder

$null = New-Item $exportfolder -type directory

## export site

Export-SPWeb $exportsite –Path $exportlocation -IncludeUserSecurity -IncludeVersions 4 
Write-host "$exportsite has been exported to $exportlocation"

## create new site ready for import

$null = New-SPWeb $importlocation -Template "$webTemplate" 
Write-host "$importlocation created ready for import"

## import site

Import-SPWeb $importlocation –Path $exportlocation -IncludeUserSecurity –UpdateVersions 2 
Write-host "$exportsite has been imported to $importlocation" -foregroundcolor "Green"